Linq2db column display attribute
I am trying to set display attribute to column in T4.
This
    LoadSqlServerMetadata("127.0.0.1,1433", "dataBase");
    Tables["Contract"].Columns["ContractTermInDays"].AliasName = "Contract terms in days";                                                                                                                             
    GenerateModel();

generates alias variable. I want something like
    LoadSqlServerMetadata("127.0.0.1,1433", "dataBase");
    Tables["Contract"].Columns["ContractTermInDays"].**DisplayAttribute **= "Contract terms in days";                                                                                                                              
    GenerateModel();

and get it in code
string displayAttribute = typeof(Contract).GetFieds[0].GetAttribute("DisplayAttribute").ToString();

Please, help to achieve this! May be I need to use something else? I just want to obtain another name of column from generated code by T4 template.
This is ok:
Tables["Contract"].Columns["ContractTermInDays"].Description = "Contract Term In Days";

but I can't obtain it in code...
Of course I can use Dictionary<ColumnName, DisplayName>, but I want to know more about linq2db.
Thank you.
Can't find anything useful in google or either on linq2db github repo.

I found the solution. In T4 you need to write
Tables["Contract"].Columns["ContractTermInDays"].Attributes.Add(new Attribute("MyDisplayName", "\"Contract Term In Days\""));

but how i can find this? where i can read about syntax of T4 for linq2db?

You posted this as an answer, and it sounds like one at the beginning, but then it sounds like it’s more of a question? How do you know this works if you’re not able to answer the questions you pose?

Thanks for comment. I know this work, because I downloaded linq2db project from github and looked in *.TT files for something useful. There I found this code. I tried it and it works. But i want to know what else i can do with columns before the code is generated.

Ah, I see now. In that case, you should post the last past as a new question, and link back to this question for context.
